# ¿Qué me falta en componentDidUpdate para que las categorias rendericen el contenido?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando hacer un proyecto con React y usando react-router-dom las rutas es decir el path si me lo cambia correctamente pero el renderizado no ocurre creo que me faltaria algun condicional en el `componentDidUpdate`, por favor ayuda.

```js
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      latestNews: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const latestNews = await api.latest();

    if (latestNews) {
      this.setState({
        latestNews: latestNews.slice(0, 10),
        isLoading: false
      });
    }
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      prevProps.location !== this.props.location &&
      this.props.location.pathname === "/search"
    ) {
      const searchResults = await api.busqueda(
        this.props.location.searchParams
      );
      if (searchResults) this.setState({ latestNews: searchResults });
    } 
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, latestNews } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={3}
          align="center"
          style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
        >
          {isLoading &&
            Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => (
              <Grid item xs={12} lg={4} key={index}>
                <Skeleton width={282} height={337} />
              </Grid>
            ))}

          {latestNews.length > 0 &&
            latestNews.map(latestNew => (
              <Grid item xs={12} lg={4} key={latestNew.news_id}>
                <Card data={latestNew} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: Me causa ruido esta validacion, prevProps.location !== this.props.location, por que haces esa validacion, no seria mejor validar con alguna propiedad del objeto location?

Comment: ¿como cual? ¿cual seria una mejor condicion?, en el componente category estoy usando match.params ¿no sera por eso que me falla el renderizado, por que en uno uso location y en el otro match.params?